# Scraping a web document along with computed styles

Tags: python, web-scraping

There are a lot of web scraping engines, namely in python but they focus on the content only. Is there a way to scrape a text content of a page along with the computed styles applied to the text, such as `font-face`, `font-size`, `line-height`, `color`, `background` etc?

Comment: what do you mean by content only? web scrapers use a mix of xpath, css, and html parsers to interact with the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use "value_of_css_propert"
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/value_of_css_property-element-method-selenium-python/